# How can I research some paper shares I found?

Tags: shares, private-company, share-certificate

I recently found old paper shares, but I couldn't find any information online about the companies.

Where to find data, and how?

Companies:

- Tally-Ho Ventures (TLYH), 7500 shares, 2006 May
- COA Development Corp, 1500 shares, 2001 April
- Images of Life, 1000 shares, 2001 May

Any ideas, how to research? Companies seem to be delisted, or maybe OTC, hard to find info.

Comment: Are you in the US / are these US companies?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article I found on what you're asking, which you can read by going to: https://finance.zacks.com/determine-worth-old-stock-certificates-6592.html

> Determine whether the company is still traded on a stock exchange. This can be done by searching major financial websites. If the stock has split over the years, the amount listed might not be the amount your certificate is worth.
> Contact the stock certificate's transfer agent, who is responsible for keeping records for stockholders. The agent is listed on the certificate itself.
> Contact the state agency that handles incorporations if the transfer agent no longer exists. The proper state is the one where the company originally was incorporated.
> Search the company's history if none of the earlier steps work. Sources of company histories include the Capital Changes Reporter, Moody's Manuals and the U.S. Library of Congress.
> Contact the new company's investor-relations department if a search of the company's history reveals that it merged or was acquired by another company.
> Contact your stockbroker to search the stock's worth via its CUSIP number if the steps given earlier yield no results. This number is printed on the back of the stock certificate.
> Use a fee-based service to search your stock's history if the earlier steps come up empty. Fees can range from $40 to $85 or more.
> Determine the collectible value of your certificate if it no longer has stock value. A stock can have worth based on who signed it, historical interest, or the engraving. This value can be found by contacting dealers, researching libraries, or searching listings on eBay.

By the way, I looked up Tally-Ho, and hey have a website at http://www.tallyhoventures.com/, which reads:

> SINCE 2000
> TALLY-HO VENTURES, INC.
> Tally-Ho Ventures, Inc. is one of the leading media companies in the world, said no one ever. Our goal, which if we’re being honest is unrealistic, is to produce entertainment content. If by some miracle we ever do produce anything, we might throw it up on our underwhelming YouTube channel, Tally-Ho Media.

I couldn't immediately locate anything on the other two, but I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on [How-to-Find-the-Value-of-Your-Old-Stock-Certificate](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Find-the-Value-of-Your-Old-Stock-Certificat/).

The bullet points are:

> You will need:

- decent knowledge of securities
- name of the corporation and transfer agent (both found on stock certificate)
- access to corporate changes directories (check your local library)

> There are reasonably priced databases although many of those are available at your local library.
> Resources you're looking for:

- Directory of Obsolete Securities
- Robert D. Fisher Manual of Valuable and Worthless Securities
- "Survey of Predecessor and Defunct Companies" The Financial Post
- Capital Changes Reporter - Published by Commerce Clearing House